# In a triangle prove that $IG \perp BC \iff b + c = 3 a$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, centroid

Consider the triangle $ABC$. Denote the incenter with $I$, the centroid with $G$ and $AB = c$, $AC = b$, $BC = a$.

Prove that $IG \perp BC \iff b + c = 3 a$.

I have tried using centroid's and incenter's properties but to no result. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Find the slopes of $IG$ and $BC$ and then show that they are "negative reciprocals" if and only if $b+c=3a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very well known problem which can be solved using vectors or Ptolemy's theorem. By the way, the question has to be worded more clearly. Please note if $b = c$, $IG \perp BC$ and then $b+c = 3a$ is not necessarily true. So the question should ask to show $b + c = 3a$, if $b \ne c$ and $IG \perp BC$.

[image]

In $\triangle ABC$, $I$ is the incenter, $G$ is the centroid and $D, E, F$ are midpoints of sides $AB, BC, CA$ resp. We draw circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$. As $AM$ is angle bisector of $\angle A$, arc $BM = MC$. As $E$ is the midpoint of chord $BC$, $ME \perp BC$ (as arc $BM = MC$).

That leads to $ME \parallel IG$ and $\triangle AIG \sim \triangle AME \implies AI = 2 MI$.

In $\triangle BMI, \angle MBI = \angle MBC + \angle CBI = \frac{\angle A + \angle B}{2} = \angle MIB \implies BM = MI$ and we already have $BM = MC$.

Given $ABCM$ is cyclic, we use Ptolemy's theorem,

$AM \cdot BC = AC \cdot BM + AB \cdot MC$

$3 MI \cdot a = MI \cdot (b + c) \implies 3a = b + c$

Comment: This is clever!

Comment: @cosmo5 thank you

Answer (score 1):

Cooment:Considering comments by cosmo5 and dnfu I consider especial case in which the triangle is isosceles.

[image]

As can be seen in figure when $IG\perp AB$ it means the triangle is isosceles; and AC=CB, then we have:

$b+c=BF+AF+AD+DC$

$DC=CE$, $BE=BF=AC=AD\rightarrow b+c=3BE+EC$

Now we have to prove that $EC=3BE$ or $(a=BC)=4BE$ such that $b+c=3(BE+EC=a)$.

,

Comment: Though the OP fails to mention, the statement is also true for non-isosceles triangles. Such as $(3,4,5)$; $3\cdot 3 = 4+5$. You can construct this triangle with software and check if $IG \perp BC$.

Comment: @cosmo5, Hope to see such figure in your answer.

Comment: I have a make-do proof for only acute triangles. But the statement is true for all kind of triangles. So I'm hoping for someone else to answer it. For such type of questions, approaches different from synthetic ones work efficiently. I didn't mean to sound rude btw.

Comment: There are plenty of non-isosceles triangles that satisfy the OP requirements. Namely, WLOG, let $\overline{BC}=2$ and fix the origin of the axes in the midpoint of $BC$,and line $BC$ as the $x$-axis. Then taking $A$ on the ellipse with equation $$\frac{x^2}9+\frac{y^2}8=1$$ leads to a triangle with the desired properties.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first observe that since $IG \perp BC$, the following relation holds between the sides of the concave quadrilateral $CIBG$:

$$IC^2+GB^2=IB^2+GC^2 \;\;\;\;\;(1)$$

If we find all of these distances in terms of the sides of the triangle (i.e. $a,b ,$ and $c$) we will be done.

To calculate the lengths of $GB^2$ and $GC^2$ we can use Apollonius's theorem and the fact that the centroid divides medians in the ratio $2:1$,

$$  GB^2=\frac{2a^2+2c^2-b^2}{9}.$$

Similarly:

$$  GC^2=\frac{2b^2+2a^2-c^2}{9}$$

To calculate the lengths of $IC^2$ and $IB^2$ we can apply the Pythagorean Theorem, but the expression for the inradius won't play out nicely, unless we get [help from of our computer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%20%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B%28b%2Bc-a%29%28c%2Ba-b%29%28a%2Bb-c%29%7D%7Ba%2Bb%2Bc%7D%7D%2C%20x%3D%28p-b%29%5E2%2Br%5E2%2C%20p%3D%28a%2Bb%2Bc%29%2F2%2C%20a%3E0). Alternatively, if the following equality is known, $$\cos \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{s\left(s-a\right)}{2}}$$

it is easier to see that the following results hold:

$$  IC^2=\frac{a c (s - b)}{s}$$

Similarly:

$$  IB^2=\frac{a b (s - c)}{s}$$

Substituting these expressions into $Eq. (1)$:

$$\frac{c^2-b^2}{3}=a(c-b)$$
$$(c+b)(c-b)=3a(c-b)$$

which gives us both the isosceles case and the relation given in the problem statement.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Triangle ABC]

Drop a perpendicular from point $I$ on side $BC$ and let the feet of this perpendicular be $D$. $G$, $I$ and $D$ will be collinear. Drop a perpendicular from vertex $A$ on side $BC$ and let the feet of this perpendicular be $L$.

Observe that, in $\triangle ALA'$, $GD\parallel AL$ and thereafter $A'L=3A'D$.

$A'L=CL-CA'=bcos\left(\angle C\right)-\frac {a}{2}=\frac {a^{2}+b^{2}-c^{2}}{2a}-\frac {a}{2}=\frac {b^{2}-c^{2}}{2a}$

$A'D=A'B-BD=\frac {a}{2}-\left(s-b\right)$

Now, $3\{\frac {a}{2}-\left(s-b\right)\}=\frac {b^{2}-c^{2}}{2a}$ and from here simplify to get [the simplification is fairly short] $3a\left(b-c\right)=b^{2}-c^{2}$.

When $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles, then the case evidently holds but for non-isosceles triangles the $(b-c)$ cancels out and hence $b+c=3a$.